# Using @class to get access to a delegate protocol declaration

Tags: objective-c, import, header-files, forward-declaration, objective-c-protocol

I've read that you should try to use `@class` in your header file instead of `#import` but this doesn't work when your `@class` contains a delegate protocol that you're trying to use.

MyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MyCustomClass;  // <-- doesn't work for MyCustomClassDelegate, used below

@interface MyView : UIView <MyCustomClassDelegate>

@end
```

I think I'm overlooking something, is there a way to get `@class` to work in this situation or is `#import` my only choice?

Edit: One work around for this is, of course, declaring your #import MyCustomClass and MyCustomClassDelegate in the private interface section of the .m file instead of the .h file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only forward-declare a protocol in the same header file for usage in method return values or parameter types. In your case you want the class to conform to the protocol, so it won't work since it defines behavior that will be added to the class itself (i.e. the methods it will respond to).

Therefore, you must `#import` the protocol. For this reason, it is probably a good idea to split the protocol and class up into separate files. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11533804/35690) for more information.

Comment: Not to nick pits, but to be more precise: you can forward-declare a protocol, but not if you are declaring a class that conforms to that protocol (in that header file). If the protocol is only needed for a method return or parameter type, it's fine to declare it (and you use "@protocol MyProtocol;" instead of "@class MyProtocol;" to do so).

Answer (score 11):

you can use `@protocol` to forward declare a protocol if you only need it for variables such as this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol;

@interface MyClass {
    id<MyProtocol> var;
}
@end
```

In your case the declared class is trying to conform to a protocol so the compiler must know about the protocol methods at this point in order to deduce weather or not the class conforms.

In this case, I think your options are to split the protocol into its own file and `#import` that header, or declare the protocol in that header above the class declaration that uses it.

Answer (score 4):

`MyCustomClassDelegate` is a protocol, not a class. Telling the compiler about the existence of `MyCustomClass` tells it nothing about the existence of the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to declare your delegate protocol before the class:

MyCustomClass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MyCustomClass;

@protocol MyCustomClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myCustomClass:(MyCustomClass *)customClass
              didBlah:(BOOL)blah;

@end

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject <MyCustomClassDelegate>

@end
```

And you cannot even use `@protocol` to forward-declare the delegate protocol; the compiler must see the complete declaration, therefore change your `@class` for an `#import`:

MyView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCustomClass.h"    // the compile now knows what MyCustomClassDelegate is

@interface MyView : UIView <MyCustomClassDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: ehhh? I think he means the protocol is already declared in the class he is referencing so it does not need to be declared again.

Comment: @Bot Ah, yes, he just needs to use `#import` rather than `@class` then.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot forward declare a protocol you conform to.

If you are using `MyView` as a `MyCustomClassDelegate` only in `MyView`'s implementation, you can use Extension in `MyView`'s .m file, such as this:

```
#import "MyView.h"
#import "MyCustomClassDelegate.h"

@interface MyView () <MyCustomClassDelegate> {

}

@end

@implementation MyView
    ...
@end
```