# ios-ntp with Xcode 7 and swift 2.0

Tags: swift, ios9, ntp

I am trying to integrate [ios-ntp](https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp) into my project, which I develop using Xcode 7, swift 2.0 and cocoapods. I am adding the library as a pod. But when I try to add `<ios-ntp/ios-ntp.h>` to my app-BridigingHeader.h, Xcode doesn't recognize it. When I try to simply import the module and use it by `#import ios_ntp` ; Xcode complains that he is not able to build module 'ios_ntp'. Am I doing smth wrong?

upd. Actually Xcode is not able to build the module due to the error

> 'GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h' file not found

but that framework is present and added in 'ios-ntp' pod spec as dependent.

Comment: Do you have ```use_frameworks!``` in your Podfile?

Comment: @rudd yes I have. just updated the question.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/huynguyencong/NHNetworkTime with Swift compatible and more advance features

Comment: I would recommend - https://github.com/lyft/Kronos Elegant NTP date library in Swift
- https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift NTP library for Swift and Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `#import` the library in your bridging header, Cocoapods should take care of making your pods available in Swift.

In your Swift files, have you tried `import ios_ntp` to import the library?

EDIT: Think I got it. Not 100% sure on why this is happening, but my hunch is that it's related to Cocoapods and ios-ntp's dependency on CocoaAsyncSocket. Something about ios-ntp's import of a CocoaAsyncSocket header is creating a circular dependency, which is borking ios-ntp's build.

Solution:
https://github.com/ruddct/ios-ntp should do the trick, that branch contains a few very minor header changes to forward declare the CocoaAsyncSocket stuff in ios-ntp's headers, which fixes the issue.

See [How to prevent circular reference when Swift bridging header imports a file that imports Hopscotch-Swift.h itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670431/how-to-prevent-circular-reference-when-swift-bridging-header-imports-a-file-that/28329497#28329497) for more background on this issue.

Comment: Xcode autocomplete offers me to import ios_ntp, but even if I use import ios-ntp, Xcode is unable to build the module. And I don't add iOS-ntp to bridgingHeader.h file.

Comment: thanks man, still had no chance to test your solution, but it sounds reasonable.

Comment: @rudd your fork worked for me. Thanks :-) Are you going to issue a pull request? You're a few commits behind now.

Comment: @rudd how do I install your pod over the regular one, as I am still getting this error with swift 3

Comment: @rudd sorry I am new to ios developing so I don't completely understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

When you use Pods, you have to:

1. Open Pods.xcodeproj
2. In Targets select ios-ntp
3. Select 'Build Phases' tab
4. Add GCDAsyncSocket.h and GCDAsyncUDPSocket.h to Compile Sources and Headers
5. Remember to set 'Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules' to Yes in ios-ntp

For me, this works.