# bridging swift and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have objective-c project and I added swift files in it. i created bridge file and imported swift file in some header files without problems.

But I need to import some header files to swift files by adding them in the `"<project-name>-Bridging-Header.h"` file.

If I put header file in that bridge file and this header file was import swift file before; Xcode give me error message: "file not found" for the swift bridge file.

i.e:

- I have project name called: "ProjectBlaBla"
- I have header file called "readingPage.h"
- I have swift file called: "readingSwift.swift"
- swift bridge file's name: "ProjectBlaBla-Swift.h"
- I created header bridge file: "ProjectBlaBla-Bridging-Header.h"
- I imported "ProjectBlaBla-Swift.h" in "readingPage.h" file without problem and used swift classes inside objective-c
- when I import "readingPage.h" in the "ProjectBlaBla-Bridging-Header.h", I got error message in "readingPage.h" said: `"ProjectBlaBla-Swift.h file not found"`

  any suggestions ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to reference -Swift.h files directly or indirectly in -Bridging-Header.h files.

If you open -Swift.h, you will see a line near the top, in my case line 99: `#import "/Users/.../...-Bridging-Header.h"`, meaning -Swift.h already imports -Bridging-Header.h, so importing back creates a circular dependency.

To avoid this, any header you import in -Bridging-Header.h must use forward references to Swift classes or protocols it uses as described in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670431/how-to-prevent-circular-reference-when-swift-bridging-header-imports-a-file-that).

In short, if `readingPage.h` uses a Swift class named `MySwiftClass` you should:

1. Remove any references to `-Swift.h` from `readingPage.h`.
2. Import `-Swift.h` in `readingPage.m`
3. Insert `@class MySwiftClass;` into `readingPage.h` before the class is used, letting Objective-C know that such a class exists and is declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the bridging header path is correct. On the left, select your project name -> TARGETS -> Build Settings -> search for Objective-C Bridging Header. Refer the photo below.

[image: Bridging Header]

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1. Import the "ProjectBlaBla-Swift.h" inside the "readingPage.m" file instead of "readingPage.h" file
2. Create a new PCH file named "Prefix.pch" and import "ProjectBlaBla-Swift.h" inside the "Prefix.pch" file.

Note: Prefix.pch is a precompiled header which makes  compiling faster. You do not need to reimport any files that are imported in prefix.ch file.