# Accessing property of forwardly declared enum from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

Given that there is an ObjC compatible enum written in Swift:

```
// from MessageType.swift
@objc enum MessageType: Int {
    case one
    case two
}
```

and an ObjC class with a property of type `MessageType` which has to be forwardly declared:

```
// from Message.h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MessageType);

@interface Message: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MessageType messageType;
@end
```

In order to use the `Message`in the rest of the Swift codebase, the `Message.h` was added into the bridging header:

```
// from App-Bridging-Header.h
#import "Message.h"
```

Now, imagine there is a Swift class that tries to read the `messageType` property:

```
// from MessageTypeReader.swift
class MessageTypeReader {
    static func readMessageType(of message: Message) -> MessageType {
        return message.messageType
    }
}
```

The compilation would fail with the following error:

```
Value of type 'Message' has no member 'messageType'
```

My question would be: Is there a way to forwardly declare a Swift enum in order for the `MessageTypeReader` to be able to access the property?

> Note: I am aware of the possibility of rewriting the Message into Swift or importing App-Bridging-Header.h into Message.h, but that is not an option here, I am looking for a solution that would work with the current setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess one reason to use NS_ENUM on Objective-C side is to have compile time checks whether the switch statement usages are exhaustive.

If that's the case one could utilize C unions.

**Objective-C Header**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MessageType);

union MessageTypeU {
    MessageType objc;
    NSInteger swift;
};


@interface Message : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) union MessageTypeU messageType;

@end
```

So the basic idea is:

> Swift imports C unions as Swift structures. Although Swift doesn’t support natively declared unions, a C union imported as a Swift structure still behaves like a C union.
>
> ...
>
> Because unions in C use the same base memory address for all of their fields, all of the computed properties in a union imported by Swift use the same underlying memory. As a result, changing the value of a property on an instance of the imported structure changes the value of all other properties defined by that structure.

see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_structs_and_unions_in_swift

**Objective-C Implementation Example**

```
@interface Message ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) union MessageTypeU messageType;

@end


@implementation Message


- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _messageType.objc = MessageTypeTwo;
        [self testExhaustiveCompilerCheck];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)testExhaustiveCompilerCheck {
    
    switch(self.messageType.objc) {
        case MessageTypeOne:
            NSLog(@"messageType.objc: one");
            break;
        case MessageTypeTwo:
            NSLog(@"messageType.objc: two");
            break;
    }
    
}

@end
```

**Usage on Swift Side**

Since the messageType.swift property comes originally from the Swift side (see definition of MessageType) we can safely use force-unwrap.

```
class MessageTypeReader {

    static func readMessageType(of message: Message) -> MessageType {
        return MessageType(rawValue: message.messageType.swift)!
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, my only concern is that it changes the API as there will have to be extra `.swift` and `.objc` for each enum, perhaps I should have been even more specific in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421367/2907715) by [Cristik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974224/cristik) (all credit goes to them):

- In `Message.h`, declare `messageType` as `NSInteger` :

  ```
  @interface Message : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger messageType;
  @end
  ```

  Using `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` [is recommended](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/improving_objective-c_api_declarations_for_swift) by Apple, but not necessary here.
- In Swift, add the following `Message` extension :

  ```
  extension Message {
      var messageType: MessageType {
          guard let type = MessageType(rawValue: self.__messageType) else {
              fatalError("Wrong type")
          }
          return type
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Isn't this going to make `messageType` not enumerable in ObjC?

Comment: @MiroslavKovac You're correct. Currently, circular references aren't supported.