# After adding .h file to bridging header, project is not building? Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have my bridging header file where I added new objective c file:

`#import "MyFile.h"`

Then I hit run and project is not building. I got errors like:

`Cannot find interface declaration`

`Expected type`

`Cannot find protocol declaration`

`failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData....`

And others. Xcode tells that errors randomly. I cleaned project and got different other errors. Then, I remove `MyFile` from bridging header file. And now project is building correctly without any errors. Why? How to solve it?

Comment: For a starter, it should be `#import "MyFile.h"` (with double quotation marks).

Comment: Edited question. Sorry. It is not a problem

Comment: I love it when people don't post their real code :( – My next guess: You have some circular import. Does "MyFile.h" import the generated Swift header ("YourProject-Swift.h")?

Comment: is Objective-C Bridging Header path in Build Settings correct?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670431/how-to-prevent-circular-reference-when-swift-bridging-header-imports-a-file-that.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it is pretty sad when people don't post code. But, I think it is not needed here. Yes, MyFile.h has #import "MyProject-Swift.h". It seems problem.

Comment: You should import "MyProject-Swift.h" in the implementation file "MyFile.m" only. If that is not possible (and if the other Q&A does not answer your question) then we need a [mcve].