# How to solve 'Expected a type' error in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am a beginner to the Objective C project.
In Swift, we implemented a bridging header to use Objective C and imported it.
However, a beep error occurs.

The following is the line where the error occurs in `importedVC.h`.

```
+ (void)moveToBannerTarget:(UINavigationController *)navigation element:(BannerElement *)element;
+ (void)moveToGroupInviteView:(UINavigationController *)navigation element:(GroupListElement *)element;
```

The following is the class where the error occurred.

```
// BannerElement.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BannerElement : NSObject <NSCopying, IGListDiffable>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *target;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bannerRef;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bannerTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bannerType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bannerId;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat width;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat height;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

---
// GroupListelement.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    GroupListTypeMain = 0,
    GroupListTypeMyGroup,
    GroupListTypeProduct,
    GroupListTypeMember,
} GroupListType;

@interface GroupListElement : NSObject <NSCopying, IGListDiffable>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *deactivateDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *shareUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *productList;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger members;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger products;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL privated;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL latest;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL selected;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isOwner;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (instancetype)initWithSectionInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: You need to declare what `IGListDiffable` is. What is it? Is it a protocol? Where is it declared?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532888/objective-c-protocol-forward-declarations